# List processes in a named nspawn container

Tags: systemd

I've been using `pstree` with pid of the `systemd-nspawn` or `systemd` process to get a convenient list of processes running "inside" a particular container/machine/namespace.

Is there a convenient or intended way to get a list by container name? (Obviously it can be scripted as a workaround.)